# Why is my All Accounts > All Web site Data empty in Google Analytics, but specific accounts are nonempty?

Tags: google-analytics

I'm trying to consolidate a Google Data Studio report with traffic from all my client's sites. However, when I go to Google Analytics, and select "All accounts" on Analytics accounts, again on "All accounts" on Properties and apps, and finally on "All web site data" in views, there's no data at all. No traffic, nada.

However, if I select (only some) specific accounts, and apps, I do see traffic.

Does someone know why this happen? I would expect "all web site data" to be an aggregation...of all web site data.